# How do I select a vertex in edit mode

Tags: animation, vertices, shape-keys

I've imported an stl into blender, and I'm trying to create morph targets. For some reason, when I go into edit mode, I can't select the vertex. When I click the window it just moves the crosshair with a circle thing aroud, but does not actually select a vertex. What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Blender, by default, uses the Right Click to select things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're left-clicking.  Blender uses *Right-Click* to select. if you don't like this, you can change it in your user preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>), though there are some advantages to just getting used to it so you can follow what everyone else is doing with Blender.

Comment: User Preferences Keystroke is useful